# How to apply quantile clipping to Seismic Data?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, quantile

Currently I am trying to apply **quantile clipping** to seismic data using [segyio](https://github.com/equinor/segyio) to access Trace data and Numpy to perform data processing.
I have written the following functions:

```
def clip(file,value):
traces = file.trace
for i,_ in enumerate(traces):
        traces[i] = np.where(traces[i]>value,value,traces[i])
        traces[i] = np.where(traces[i]<-value,-value,traces[i])
```

and

```
def qclip(file,value):
    data = np.array([i for i in file.trace ])
    clipval = np.quantile(np.abs(data),value)
    clip(file,clipval)
```

**qclip** takes segyio opened file and value in [0,1] to apply quantile clipping to the traces.
It works but the value of clipping applied is very different from the value i get from Seismic Unix using:

```
sugain < infile qclip=value > outfile
```

here is the implementation of [sugain qclip](https://github.com/JohnWStockwellJr/SeisUnix/blob/master/src/su/main/amplitudes/sugain.c).

Answer (score 0):

Try np.percentile instead of np.quantile